# Unable to connect to snowflake environment through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to `snowflake` with Python but getting the below error.

**Code:**

```
import snowflake.connector 

con = snowflake.connector.connect(
  user='<username>',
  password='<password>',
  account='<org_name>.us-west-2.privatelink'
)
```

**Error:**

> snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: Failed to get the
> response. Hanging? method: post, url:
> https://<org_name>.us-west-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=9b7cb3c2-b7b9-4ab6-aa11-d843f3e36c6f&request_guid=67ba65fb-def5-4008-9896-de1331c2bb46

**Notes:**

1. I am using Python version 3.7.6
2. `snowflake.connector` package is also installed
3. In case of any proxy issue, No_proxy is also set up in in environment variables.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Are you trying to connect via the PrivateLink or directly via Internet? PrivateLink accounts are not allowed via internet.

Comment: @Sergiu: I am trying to connect via the PrivateLink. I am using Organizational VPN over the internet.

Comment: Are you able to connect with Public end point to this snowflake account? Does snowsql connect successfully to this account over privatelink from this same host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the Private link account name is correct?
This should be either in accountlocator.region.privatelink or regionless format like orgname-accountname.privatelink.

Also, Verify if you are able to resolve Private Link host to AWS VPC endpoint DNS value.

nslookup account-locator.us-west-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com

nslookup orgname-accountname.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HowTo-Troubleshoot-Privatelink-configuration-for-Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved.
Had to use a different version of Anaconda to get it work. I used conda 4.7.12 and it resolved the issue.